# Subdomain not working in Microsoft Azure

Tags: azure, dns, subdomain, ubuntu-16.04, azure-virtual-machine

I have hosted my project in **Microsoft Azure** by creating **Linux VM**. I have used **Ubuntu 16.04** for my VM. I have created a subdomain there with the name **app** so that i can access my website as **app.example.com**.

I have purchased the domain from **register.com** . I have also pointed my website there & created a **A** record there.

All are working fine & i can access both my main domain & subdomain like **www.example.com** & **app.example.com** but after couple of day the subdomain stop working

Please help.

Comment: Does your VM's public IP address changed?

Comment: No its a static IP address. Its not changed

Comment: Please run nslookup, can you find the IP in it?

Comment: Yes. Its working fine & showing my ip & domain name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your description, maybe we can use `nslookup` to test domain name.
Like this:

```
C:\Users>nslookup jasontest.azurexxxxx.xxx
Server:  UnKnown
Address:  2404:f801:10:12e:fe::2

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:    jasontest.azurexxxxx.xxx
Address:  52.184.152.116
```

Then we can find the Azure VM's public IP address via Azure portal, if the IP address have changed, we should **replace** the right public IP address to A record.

By the way, in Azure the public IP address we should use **static** IP, in this way, public IP address will not change.

Can your browse your website in your Azure VM? use `curl localhost`.

Comment: Yes. I am using a static IP & Its not changed.

Comment: I have also created a *A* record in register.com by using above ip.

Comment: nslookup can return the right public IP address? but still can't browse your website?

Comment: @pkk For test, please SSH to your Azure VM, please check your project status. maybe your project is stopped.

Comment: I can access my main domain & can't access my subdoamin after   couple of days of inactivity.

Comment: i checked the linux  instance(resource) status from azure portal & its running.

Comment: @pkk maybe we should login this VM and check the app status. could you please login this VM and check the app status?

Comment: I have created a LAMP stack there for website & all are running fine. But i think the apache server not working sometime from your above point.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144900/discussion-between-jason-ye-msft-and-pkk).

Comment: Ok. Thanks @Jason